# How do I link an installed app in iBooks Author?

Tags: applications, ibooks-author

I'm trying to making an iBook for educational purposes, and in that book I linked to web pages, embedded a video, embedded an image. I want to link to an installed iPad app in my iBook, is it possible in iBooks Author?. If so, then can someone guide me how to do this or provide some link for that. Any help should be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in WebKit so it is probably possible in iBooks too. The URL depends on the application, as it's the developer who chooses it. [More info here](http://appcubby.com/urls/), with the example of launch center, an app which is basically a list of URLs to apps.

Try it with the free app Twitterrific (make your link to `twitterrific://` – no `http://`!).

Comment: This seems correct, however within iBooks I see no way to make a link such as "twitterrific://" without creating a custom widget. The standard way of entering a hyperlink automatically prepends the "http://" no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a URL-shortener service, like tinyurl.com or similar.
Make the tinyurl redirect to for instance twitterific://

Comment: That might be a clever hack indeed. Have you verified that it actually works? And it probably will not work while you are offline.